# SDL2 help (multi-threading)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I know you can't do any rendering in separate threads using SDL2, but what about events like `leftbutton1down` etc?

I don't see how I can continuously draw at lets say, 60fps, while having the event poll in the same thread, so, wondering what's the best structure to use for my game.

Current idea (each separate thread separated by ','):
Main thread with drawing + physics, event polling (inputs)

Comment: Using threads may be a good architecture idea to explore, but have you tested the performance of running the rendering and event polling in the same thread? (Personal experience has shown me way more than 60fps with one thread)

Comment: I second @loaner9's statement. I've never found event polling to be a significant portion of my execution time. However, there isnt a technical reason why you cant do this in general, but SDL may not behave as expected on all platforms if it isn't something they specifically allow.

Comment: Many games in years past have managed good frame rates on single core machines. Obviously you don't *need* multiple threads.

Comment: Documentation for [SDL_PumpEvents](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) (which is called implicitly by `SDL_PollEvent`) says "This should only be run in the thread that initialized the video subsystem". Mostly depends on OS, sometimes it seems like you can, sometimes it deadlocks instead. Why is event handling appears to be heavy though? It is one of the most lightweight things, physics or animation are not.

Comment: Doesn't the event poll yield? I don't see how I can multi-task with that unless I could push my own "events"